# Extending an inner product to the completion?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

> Let $X,Y$ be normed vector spaces. Suppose we have already defined a bilinear form
>   $$ X \times Y \rightarrow k$$ 
>   that satisfies $$|\langle x,y \rangle| \le |x|_X |y|_Y$$ and $k$ is complete scalar field $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$.
>
> Now let us take the completion of $X$ and $Y$ wrt to their norms.  Can we extend this to a bilinear form on the completion?

---

I think so. This is my argument:

Let us take [the completion](http://www.math.udel.edu/~fjsayas/teaching/math806/Completion.pdf) where an element is an equivalence class Cauchy sequence modulo sequences convergent to $0$ in the original norm. Let $[(x_n)], [(y_n)]$ be two elements in completions, $X',Y'$.

Define, 
$$ \langle [(x_n)], [(y_n)] \rangle := \lim_{n} \langle x_n, y_n \rangle $$ 
**This is well defined:** The sequence on RHS is Cauchy, since 
$$ |\langle x_n, y_n \rangle - \langle x_m, y_m \rangle | \le  |\langle x_n - x_m, y_n \rangle | + |\langle x_m, y_n - y_m | \le |x_n - x_m|_X |y_n|_Y + |x_m|_X |y_n- y_m|_Y  $$ 
using original condition. So the limit of RHS exists.

Also this is independent of the equivalence class chosen, since the same equation shows that limit if $x_n$ is a Cauchy sequence which limits to $0$, then the limit of the inner product is $0$.

**The inequality still holds:** Taking norms, since limits commute with it, we have 
$$ | \lim \langle x_n, y_n \rangle | \le \lim |x_n|_x |y_n|_Y = |[x_n]|_{X'} |[y_n]|_{Y'}$$ 
by the definition of the norm in the completion.

---

Is the statement true? and if so why (and possibly comment if my argument is correct).

Comment: I think it would help a lot if you would write out the details of your arguments.

Comment: Ok, I have added details to my proof. Sorry for being unclear.